# Proccess System.exe cosumes a lot of CPU in Windows Server 2008-r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [High CPU usage by the “system” process](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process)

I have a PC with Windows Server2008-r2 and in the proccess list the proccess System.exe consumes a lot of CPU constantly. Can you help me?

Comment: Does it actually say `System.exe` or just `System`? What PID does this process have?

Comment: Is System, and it has PID 4

Comment: PID 4 represents the Windows NT kernel, not a userspace process. High CPU use might be caused by a buggy device driver.

Comment: As this is a different OS version (Win 8 and Win Server 2008 aren't the same) @GrahamWager I'm not so sure this is a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from Microsoft Technet.  It reveals a welath of information on a process and associated DLLs

Comment: I have done it but the subproccess of System doesn´t use any resources of CPU. it seems that Thread that consumes CPU is ntoskrnl.exe. This has a solution?

Comment: @user117177 FWIW, usually it's a driver error.