# Troubleshoot High CPU usage by the "System" process

Tags: windows, windows-8, performance, troubleshooting, cpu-usage

I have noticed that from some time my system is freezing and its probably caused by the high CPU usage which is caused by the system process.

All applications I'm running is the Skype, TeamSpeak and Chrome so it definitely shouldnt eat that amount of CPU.

You can see the problem itself and running processes in the screenshot below:

[image]

Sometimes CPU usage is reaching 90%, but the average usage is like 40-65%.

My PC parameters:

- Windows 8 (customer preview)
- Intel Core i3 - 2350M
- 8 GB RAM

I'd appreciate any help attempt!
Regards.

**--UPDATE--**

As the user below posted a great answer, I have noticed that the process that is eating the most CPU in the system is called `Arthurx.sys`, simple google tells that it's a TPLink driver (an wifi adapter, I have bought like 2 weeks ago!) drivers has been installed from the Windows MSDN, but also tried to install the drivers from the attached CD, but it doesn't help. From the system start, it is using like 5% of the CPU only, but after 2-4 hours of working it is growing up and reaching 40-60% of the CPU usage.

Device name: `TPLink WN722N`

Comment: use xperf to trace it. But as other users told you, stop using the CP. All pre-Release version will expire in 2 weeks!

Comment: @Ramhound I have bought Windows 8 Pro via internet today and will upgrade my system within few minutes, I will keep this updated and will let you know if problem whether has been fixed or not.

Answer (score 285):

**Introduction**

High CPU usage by the "System" process can often be caused by a hardware driver issue (bug, old version, incompatility etc).

The System process loads (or hosts) multiple hardware drivers from different vendors that require higher level of memory access.   This is why diagnosing the specific culprit can require a bit of detective work as described below.

**Diagnosing the issue**

To diagnose the CPU usage issues, you should use Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) to capture CPU Sampling data / Profile.

To capture the data, [install the Windows Performance Toolkit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), which is part of the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

The Windows 10 WPT can be used on Windows 8/Server 2012, Windows 8.1/Server 2012R2 and Windows 10/Server 2016. If you still use Windows 7, use the [SDK/WPT with Build 15086](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771).

[image]
<sup>(all other entries can be unselected)</sup>

Now run `WPRUI.exe`, select `First Level`, under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**.

[image]

Now capture 1 minute of the CPU usage. After 1 minute, click on **Save**.

Now [analyze the generated ETL file with the Windows Performance Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/defrag-tools/42-wpt-cpu-analysis) by dragging and dropping the `CPU Usage (sampled)` graph to the `analysis pane` and ordering the columns like you see in the picture:

[image]

Inside WPA, [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/loading-symbols) and expand Stack of the SYSTEM process. In this demo, the CPU usage comes from the nVIDIA driver.

---

In the following demo, the CPU usage comes from the Realtek NIC driver:

[image]

---

When you see calls like *ntoskrnl.exe!**Vi**KeTrimWorkerThreadRoutine, ntoskrnl.exe!Mm**Verifier**TrimMemory, ntoskrnl.exe!**Verifier**KeLeaveCriticalRegion*, this means you have Driver Verifier enabled. This also hurts performance a lot and causes high SYSTEM usage. [Disable Driver Verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/driver-verifier#how_to_control_dv) and reboot.

[image]

---

In this demo, the driver `iai2ce.sys` (Intel Serial IO GPIO Controller driver) causes it:

[image]

---

In this example, the CPU usage comes from the file `rtsuvc.sys` which seems to be the `Realtek UVC webcam Driver`

[image]

---

This demo shows that Bitdefender driver `ignis.sys`

[image]

---

In the following example, the CPU usage is casued by the broadcom network driver `bcmwl664.sys`

[image]

---

When you see `ntoskrnl.exe!MiZeroWorkerPages` as cause, it is trickier. This means the function of the kernel which zeros the memory before it can be used again causes the high CPU usage:

[image]

There is no real way to detect which process causes it, but I know that Chrome can cause it if you have hardware acceleration enabled in Chrome. So if you see this and use Chrome, turn hardware acceleration in Chrome off.

---

When you see those **ntoskrnl.exe!RtlpGenericRandomPatternWorker, ntoskrnl.exe!RtlpTestMemoryRandomUp** calls

[image]

the CPU usage comes from the Kernel to test memory for issues (memtest). This usage is triggered via the idle maintenance task of Windows 8.1/10. You can use Task Scheduler to disable the idle task.

[image]

In Windows 10, the task is called RunFullMemoryDiagnostics under **Microsoft > Windows > MemoryDiagnostic > RunFullMemoryDiagnostic**.

[image]

---

In this case, the CPU usage seems to come from the `Data Deduplication` Feature (`dedup.sys!DdpPostCreate`) of Windows Server:

[image]

---

In this demo, the CPU usage is caused by the WIFI card driver `athrx.sys`

[image]

Search for a driver update if you see this.

---

In the following demo, a citrix driver is involved:

[image]

So contact your IT for how to solve Citrix issues.

---

In this demo, the function `usbhub.sys!UsbhPortRecycle` causes the CPU usage:

[image]

[Changing USB2.0 ports to 1.1 speed](https://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=29289&PID=144750&title=need-help-with-ntoskrnl-thread-causing-high-cpu#144750) or connecting USB drives to other USB 2.0 ports helped for some users.

---

In this case, a small amount of SYSTEM usage comes from the Acronis driver `tdrpm251.sys`:

[image]

---

In this demo, the CPU usage `ntoskrnl.exe!KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc` and `ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseSpinLock`.

[image]

so a driver is using [SpinLocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548114(v=vs.85).aspx) very heavily. Disable some devices/drivers until you see one which causes it.

---

In this case, the CPU usage is caused by the driver `L1C62x64.sys`

[image]

This is the `qualcomm atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-E gigabit Ethernet` driver. So update the driver if you see it in the stack.

---

Here, the CPU usage comes from scanning the host file (netbt.sys!DelayedScanLmHostFile)

[image]

make sure your hosts file is not too large to avoid this usage.

---

In this case, the CPU usage comes from `SRTSP64.SYS` from symantec.

[image]

Update your used symantec product to the latest version.

---

Here, the CPU usage comes from the AMD GPU driver (atikmdag.sys)

[image]

if you see this, go to AMD site and get the latest driver for your AMD card.

---

Here, the drivers TMXPFlt.sys and  VsapiNt.sys cause the high CPU usage.

[image]

From what I see, those files are part of Trend Micro AV suite. Update the tool or remove it.

---

In this example, the CPU usage comes from the function `ntoskrnl.exe!MmGetPageFileInformation`

[image]

This function gets information about the pagefile.

> Routine Description:
> This routine returns information about the currently active paging
> files.

Disable the pagefile, reboot and enable it again and see if this fixes it. Also, removing Intel services (e.g Intel Content Protection HECI Service) [seems to fixed it for a user](https://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=29289&PID=151319&title=need-help-with-ntoskrnl-thread-causing-high-cpu#151319).

---

Here, you can see that the driver `Netwtw04.sys` (Intel Wifi driver) calls the function `flushCompleteAllPendingFlushRequests` and this causes a high CPU usage.

[image]

Because the debug symbols get loaded the Windows inbox driver is used. Only here we can get debug symbols to see the callstack with the function name `flushCompleteAllPendingFlushRequests`.

Here, you should [install the latest driver from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26527/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-IT-Admins?v=t) to fix it.

---

The most complicated case of SYSTEM usage is ACPI.sys usage in the callstack:

```
Line #, DPC/ISR, Module, Stack, Count, Process, Weight (in view) (ms), TimeStamp (s), % Weight
6, , ,   |    |- ACPI.sys!ACPIWorkerThread, 40246, , 39.992,941063, , 4,13
7, , ,   |    |    ACPI.sys!RestartCtxtPassive, 40246, , 39.992,941063, , 4,13
8, , ,   |    |    ACPI.sys!InsertReadyQueue, 40246, , 39.992,941063, , 4,13
9, , ,   |    |    ACPI.sys!RunContext, 40246, , 39.992,941063, , 4,13
10, , ,   |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseSpinLock, 40246, , 39.992,941063, , 4,13
11, , ,   |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiDpcInterrupt, 40246, , 39.992,941063, , 4,13
12, , ,   |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiDispatchInterruptContinue, 40246, , 39.992,941063, , 4,13
13, , ,   |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KxRetireDpcList, 40246, , 39.992,941063, , 4,13
14, , ,   |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiRetireDpcList, 40246, , 39.992,941063, , 4,13
15, , ,   |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiExecuteAllDpcs, 40198, , 39.945,173325, , 4,13
16, , ,   |    |    |    |- ACPI.sys!ACPIInterruptDispatchEventDpc, 27565, , 27.408,930428, , 2,83
17, , ,   |    |    |    |    |- ACPI.sys!ACPIGpeEnableDisableEvents, 24525, , 24.384,921620, , 2,52
18, , ,   |    |    |    |    |    ACPI.sys!ACPIWriteGpeEnableRegister, 24525, , 24.384,921620, , 2,52
19, , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |- hal.dll!HalpAcpiPmRegisterWrite, 24421, , 24.281,015516, , 2,51
20, , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |- hal.dll!HalpAcpiPmRegisterWritePort, 24166, , 24.027,316013, , 2,48
```

this is extremely difficult to debug. In a [sysinternals topic](http://forum.sysinternals.com/search_results_posts.asp?SearchID=20161015193501&KW=ACPI%2Esys), I listed some advice:

- make sure the CPU doesn't overheat because of dust in the CPU fan
- update or re-flash the (same) BIOS/UEFI
- load default BIOS/UEFI settings
- make sure the battery is not damaged, remove the battery from the notebook or disable the battery in device manager.
- [change jumper](https://superuser.com/a/1152438/174557) [on HDD caddy](https://superuser.com/a/979767/174557) if you have replaced the DVD/Blue-Ray Drive with a Caddy to install an SSD next to your old HDD

[image]

- [disable some devices](https://superuser.com/a/1033016) as advised by this user
- if you use an Intel chipset, try to install [Intel Rapid storage Technology (RST)](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/55005/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-) to replace the standard AHCI driver from Windows. This also [seems to helped](https://superuser.com/a/1135461/174557).
- the user [Shayna](https://superuser.com/users/680808/shayna) [figured out](https://superuser.com/questions/1225147/acpi-sys23270-thead-using-12-cpu-usage-win10#comment1793520_1225147), that using [Process Hacker (started as admin)](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/downloads.php) to suspend the threads of the ACPI.sys issues "fixes" the issue for him. So try his workaround if all other steps don't fix it for you.

---

In the following demo, the Intel HD driver `igdkmd64.sys` in version .4574 for the Intel HD 630 causes the issue:

[image]

The solution is to [update to driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/98909/Intel-HD-Graphics-630) with version of at least .4590.

---

In the following case, the CPU usage of the SYSTEM process is caused by the driver `stdriverx64.sys`

[image]

This seems to be an [audio streaming driver](http://www.nch.com.au/soundtap/index.html). So update this software/driver if you see this in WPA.

---

If you see a driver called `risdxc64.sys` in callstack of SYSTEM that causes the high CPU usage, update the **Ricoh PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller** driver or disable the SD card reader in device manager if no driver update fixes it.

[image]

This SD card reader seems to be built-in to many Lenovo devices.

---

The user @stevemidgley showed a new issue of higher CPU usage with `Wdf01000.sys!FxSystemWorkItem::_WorkItemThunk`

[image]

Here you can see a driver UDE.sys causing it.

In symbol hub

[image]

I can see it belongs to Modem driver and PNP data of the trace shows `Fibocom L850-GL` (LTE Modem) as possible device:

[image]

And the solution is to disable the modem and USB composite device in device manager.

---

The user [@fajar](https://superuser.com/users/1289652/fajar) provided the following case:

[image]

Here the cpu usage is small, but if you change the view to DPC/ISR usage

[image]

you can see that the avgNetHub.sys driver causes a lof of DPC usage

[image]

The name indicates that this driver is part of AVG anti virus software. So update the software or remove it if you see this in your trace.

---

Comment: Is the full SDK needed? Or is it possible to install just the WPT and uncheck everything else? I have some problem running the SDK installed. I already have VS 2019 and a Windows SDK version 2004 (10.0.19041.0) installed, but the installation doesn't include WPT. I downloaded the SDK installer (same version), but when I run it, there's a spash screen for a second, which then disappears and nothing happens. In the end I downloaded the SDK .iso version, mounted it, and manually installed Installers\WPTx64-x86_en-us.msi

Comment: @GenePavlovsky if you already have SDK installed via VS, open control panel->installed program, select the SDK and select "change/repair" and select the WPT.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, I managed to install it already, but meanwhile the System CPU usage that I wanted to investigate disappeared...

Comment: @GenePavlovsky does it happen when the device is idle? I also covered this in the topic, here the idle maintenance task kicks up and scans the installed programs, tests RAM and other things.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes it was idle. I just replaced my thinkpad x230 stock i7-3520m motherboard with another one from AliExpress featuring a quad-core i7-3612qe CPU, and this happened. So I was wondering if it has something to do with the new hardware. It didn't happen again so who knows, maybe it was just coincidence and it was indeed that maintenance task you mentioned.

Comment: @GenePavlovsky ok, start the recording, minimize the window and when you get the issue again, wait 30s, restore the Recorder Windows and save the trace.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer! For me, the process responsible was *ntoskrnl.exe*, with the *RtlScrubMemory* function being the culprit. [Apparently](https://superuser.com/a/920309/663024) this function actually tests RAM for errors during "idle time", ironically. Just to point out that these peaks in CPU usage can be caused by benevolent automatic processes.

Answer (score 121):

This can be caused by a faulty driver or other module loaded by the system. To look inside the System process, you can use a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

Download and run it, then select the System process, right-click and select Properties:

[image]

Switch to the Threads tab (ignore the dialog box that mentions symbols):

[image]

This will show which file is using the excessive CPU usage, from which you can then attempt to diagnose it.

As others have said in the comments however, you really do need to move away from the Preview versions as soon as possible!

Comment: @Scott I noticed that you're upgrading now; if this issue is still not resolved after that, TPLink have a beta Windows 8 driver on their site available which may help. It can be found here: http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/?model=TL-WN722N&version=V1#tbl_a

Comment: It seems risdxc64.sys is a usual suspect with Thinkpad laptops which is the driver for the card reader, see e.g. here: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/Ricoh-Card-Reader-use-25-CPU/td-p/1124227 - I solved it by reinstalling the latest one on win 10

Comment: I had a similar problem in Windows 10. For me it was avc3.sys that was using a lot of cpu. Turns out to be a part of Bitdefender Antivirus Free.

Comment: @Legends you used the wrong tool. ProcExp shows a shapshot which is not that helpful. I wrote [an answer about Windows Performance Toolkit](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557) to show it in detail how to analyze cpu usage

Comment: great.. this tip works with process hacker as well... seems mine is `aswbidsdriver.sys`.. I guess you get what you pay for... Avast Free is eating a constant 5-6% of i7-8750H CPU! unacceptable

Comment: in my case, it was csagent.exe which was CrowdStrike Windows sensor.. I'm not sure what it was, but after I uninstalled that, system service reduced from about 15% to almost 0%.

Answer (score 5):

A note on loading debugging symbols to add to [magicandre1981's excellent answer](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process/1164299#1164299): if loading the symbols in Windows Performance Analyzer works correctly, after ticking *Trace > Load Symbols* you should see a progress bar on the top with **Loading symbols** which shows file names beside it and takes several minutes to complete. Also you should see many lines like the below in the Diagnostic Console:

```
SYMSRV:  File: Accessibility.ni.pdb

SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/Accessibility.ni.pdb/7B46178957827CDAB7EE4C86EDEE1DAE1/Accessibility.ni.pdb
```

If you don't see either of these, loading debug symbols likely hasn't worked and you won't be able to properly interpret your trace.

In my case initially loading debug symbols didn't work. I fixed it by following [these instructions](https://needleinathreadstack.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/symbols-do-not-load-in-windows-performance-analyzer-wpa/):

> 1. Figure out if you are using the x86 or x64 version of the Windows Performance Toolkit.
>
>    This is easy on x86 builds of Windows. On x64 builds, you can check
>      the Task Manager for the *32 tag. If it’s not there, then you’re
>      running the x64 version.
>
>    Note that WPT always installs to Program Files (x86) regardless of
>      architecture.
> 2. Copy the `dbghelp.dll` and `symsrv.dll` files from the correct debugger directory to the Windows Performance Toolkit directory.  On
>      my system, the relevant directories are:
>
>    `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64` and
>      `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit`
> 3. Restart Windows Performance Analyzer so that the correct version of dbghelp.dll is picked up.

Comment: you should add this to my answer as an edit. this is not a real answer

Comment: Edits are usually rejected if they don't match author's intent. I think this is ok as a partial answer and no idea why it's reported.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that the CPU usage was ridiculously high when downloading anything (up to 4 GHz). I have a predator Helios 300 with a Killer WiFi card, so the Killer driver was pre-installed. I used Process Explorer to go into `System`'s properties → Threads tab and found out that "kfeco10x64.sys" was causing the high CPU usage. Since "kfeco10x64.sys" was part of the killer network service, I disabled it by running `msconfig` and unchecking every service from "Rivet Networks".

After a restart, the problem went away for me. Most importantly, there doesn't seem to be any speed reduction when downloading. I hope this helps anybody who faces the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/522567) added by [@magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981) is the key to solve any problem. 
My case wasn't listed there, but I found a similar word in stack described under `The most complicated case of SYSTEM usage is ACPI.sys usage in the callstack:` section. 
In my case installing `Intel Rapid Storage` driver was helped. I didn't expect this as far as all were working for a lot of time without this driver and without any CPU issues. 
I put my stack here, probably somebody will found this answer by similar keywords.

```
Line #, Process, Stack, Count, Weight (in view) (ms), TimeStamp (s), % Weight
3, , [Root], 45104, 45,300.439000, , 16.21
4, ,   ntoskrnl.exe!KiStartSystemThread, 45104, 45,300.439000, , 16.21
5, ,   ntoskrnl.exe!PspSystemThreadStartup, 45104, 45,300.439000, , 16.21
6, ,   |- ntoskrnl.exe!SMKM_STORE_MGR<SM_TRAITS>::SmCompressCtxWorkerThread, 38830, 38,997.540000, , 13.95
7, ,   |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SMKM_STORE_MGR<SM_TRAITS>::SmCompressCtxProcessEntry, 38708, 38,874.943400, , 13.91
8, ,   |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!memcpy, 33888, 34,032.390100, , 12.18
9, ,   |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!memcpy<itself>, 33655, 33,795.069100, , 12.09
10, ,   |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiDpcInterrupt, 228, 232.331300, , 0.08
11, ,   |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw, 4, 3.989700, , 0.00
12, ,   |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiInterruptDispatch, 1, 1.000000, , 0.00
13, ,   |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!RtlCompressBuffer, 2571, 2,585.541600, , 0.93
14, ,   |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SMKM_STORE_MGR<SM_TRAITS>::SmCompressCtxProcessReadyQueue, 2015, 2,022.554900, , 0.72
15, ,   |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool, 129, 129.294600, , 0.05
16, ,   |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SMKM_STORE_MGR<SM_TRAITS>::SmCompressCtxProcessEntry<itself>, 63, 62.901700, , 0.02
17, ,   |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquireSpinLockExclusive, 31, 31.208200, , 0.01
18, ,   |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!MetroHash64::Hash, 10, 10.033100, , 0.00
19, ,   |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiDpcInterrupt, 1, 1.019200, , 0.00
20, ,   |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SMKM_STORE_MGR<SM_TRAITS>::SmCompressCtxWorkerThread<itself>, 78, 78.477100, , 0.03
21, ,   |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquireSpinLockExclusive, 39, 39.068100, , 0.01
22, ,   |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject, 5, 5.051400, , 0.00
23, ,   |- ntoskrnl.exe!SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStWorkerThread, 5420, 5,445.923200, , 1.95
24, ,   |- ntoskrnl.exe!SmKmStoreHelperWorker, 495, 496.265200, , 0.18
25, ,   |- ntoskrnl.exe!SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStReadThread, 359, 360.710600, , 0.13
26, , n/a, 16760, 16,773.871200, , 6.00
```

**Update:** Unfortunately issue came back. After restart PC works fine some time but then same CPU leak appear with the same stack

Comment: in your case it is [memcpy function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/memcpy-wmemcpy?view=vs-2019) which is called by memory compression, but it could be that the Intel driver leaks memory and this triggers memory compression.

Comment: look for [memory leaks/zombie processes](https://superuser.com/a/1326187/174557)

Comment: also try to [disable memory compression](https://superuser.com/a/1133340/174557) because SmCompressCtxWorkerThread is the [memory compression of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/952142/174557)

Comment: task manager/process explorer have an option to show handles for a process in a column. look which programs has too many handles and close the program.

Answer (score -3):

First, the review and information supplied is very informative, however you can usually figure this out with much less intelligence!  I simply used MSCOFIG.EXE and a binary search to isolate the offending service.  I have found most problems like this are caused by Intel software.  I start by disabling any service that does not have a company name.  Then I start on Intel services.   Then the full binary search.  Usually takes an hour at most to fix the problem in someone's PC. 
Intel was never a good computer company, and their software demonstrates it.  Let's face it the Pentium architecture was a decade old when it was released. Who would have built a computer architecture with paged memory in the days of VAX?  Well, I won't bore you with the history.  Not that I am fan of AMD or Microsoft either.  Perhaps someday we'll get back to building real computers again.

Comment: You do realize that the VAX uses paged memory, right? And why wouldn't you use paged memory today?