# Windows 10 - hal.dll / ACPI.sys / ntoskrnl.exe with high cpu (WPR file included)

Tags: cpu, windows-10

I have a dell inspiron 3421 with windows 10 enterprise, fresh install.

With no programs running, I get 40% cpu usage from "System" and "Interrupts" combined.

Searching the problem I downloaded the Windows Performance Recorder and the Windows Performance Analyzer. In the "DPC and ISR Usage by Module, Stack" tab you can see that hal.dll itself is using more than 10% cpu at all times.

As far as I know it is all Windows' stuff, not 3rd party.

All the drivers are up to date. I'm not sure what to do next.

Link to Windows Performance file (.etl)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B29xKdkT5wYzYXRYTncyR2JURmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: HAL = Hardware Extraction Layer.  "Interrupts" are used by hardware for signalling.  "System" is the user the system itself uses for running processes.  So your hardware is the issue, for some reason.  Since it's working at all, it's most likely a driver issue.  Does the problem exist in Safe Mode?  You say your drivers are all up to date, how did you acquire the drivers exactly, and were they all branded at Windows 10 compatible?

Comment: Is it like this right after boot, or does it take a while for the problem to show up?
Have you tried resetting all of your BIOS (firmeware) settings to default?

Comment: Enterprise software on a consumer notebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Dell Inspiron 3421` comes with a DVD drive. You have replaced it with a HDD caddy to also install a `Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB` next to your old `Seagate Samsung Spinpoint M8 1TB`.

You have to look if your caddy has a jumper and if yes, change the position of the jumper.

[image]

Comment: Great, Worked like a charm! I would have never guessed, Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear this. I saw this some time ago on msfn: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/172738-on-optical-bay-hd-caddy-adapters-for-laptops/?p=1086150

Comment: Wow, ty, it's finally fixed. BUT, I don't see any jumper stuff on my caddy or drive, so I basically can't use my 2nd drive while plying games. Is it possible my caddy/drive doesn't have the right jumper stuff, or am I probably missing something?

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar replace the caddy with one that has a jumper

Comment: For some caddies, the jumper is on the outside boundary.

Comment: @chuckskull if you have such an picture, please add it to the answer

Comment: @magicandre1981 Unfortunately, I couldn't take a picture at that moment. It was the same kind of jumper just on the side of the caddy. If one sees it, one quickly recognize it.