# Windows 10 boot time : previously 20 seconds, now 6-8 X more

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, start-screen

Previously it took about 20-30 seconds to boot my Windows 10 Computer.
I just don't understand why it does now take up to eight-times longer to start up, even though I have disabled most the useless services on Windows. I cannot find out how to fix this issue.

***EDIT 1***: I think it is maybe because of this (it is thrown four separate times):

```
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
```

***EDIT 2:*** [WPT report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/epoxxbjjlvl4apw/DESKTOP-OTIF3AP.04-23-2017.21-21-57.Boot_1.etl.zip?dl=0)

The full log :

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Version 10.0 (Build 14393)
 4 23 2017 16:08:20.493
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\hal.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\kd.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\werkernel.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CLFS.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\PSHED.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\BOOTVID.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\FLTMGR.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\msrpc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ksecdd.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\clipsp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\cmimcext.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ntosext.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\CI.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\cng.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\Wdf01000.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WDFLDR.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\acpiex.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\WppRecorder.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ACPI.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\WMILIB.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WdBoot.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\intelpep.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WindowsTrustedRT.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\WindowsTrustedRTProxy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pcw.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\msisadrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pci.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\vdrvroot.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\pdc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\CEA.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\partmgr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\spaceport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volmgr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volmgrx.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mountmgr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\iaStorA.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\storport.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\EhStorClass.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\fileinfo.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Wof.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WdFilter.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\NTFS.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Fs_Rec.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ndis.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\NETIO.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\ksecpkg.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tcpip.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\fwpkclnt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\wfplwfs.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\fvevol.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volume.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volsnap.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdyboost.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\mup.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\iorate.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\hwpolicy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\disk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CLASSPNP.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\cdrom.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\filecrypt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Null.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Beep.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\BasicDisplay.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\BasicRender.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Npfs.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Msfs.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\tdx.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\netbt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\afd.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\vwififlt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pacer.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\netbios.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rdbss.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\csc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\nsiproxy.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\npsvctrig.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mssmbios.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\gpuenergydrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\dfsc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\SysWow64\drivers\AsIO.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ahcache.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\compositebus.inf_amd64_a140581a8f8b58b7\CompositeBus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kdnic.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\umbus.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\igdkmd64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\HDAudBus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ucx01000.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\USBXHCI.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\TeeDriverW8x64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\athw8x.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\vwifibus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rt640x64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\usbehci.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\i8042prt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kbdclass.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CmBatt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\wmiacpi.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\intelppm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\AsHIDSwitch64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\NdisVirtualBus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\swenum.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdpbus.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\usbhub.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\RTKVHD64.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ksthunk.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\UsbHub3.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\IntcDAud.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\fastfat.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\usbccgp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\hidusb.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mouhid.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mouclass.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kbdhid.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\monitor.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\wcifs.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\luafv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\storqosflt.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\wcnfs.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\registry.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\lltdio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\rspndr.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\wanarp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mslldp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ndisuio.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nwifi.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WudfPf.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\bowser.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mpsdrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb20.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\Ndu.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tcpipreg.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mmcss.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb10.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\peauth.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWoW64\speedfan.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\srvnet.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\srv2.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\srv.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WdFilter.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\vwifimp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tunnel.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\Drivers\WdNisDrv.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\condrv.sys
```

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU Usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll analyze your boot

Comment: Thanks for your help : here is the result : https://www.dropbox.com/s/epoxxbjjlvl4apw/DESKTOP-OTIF3AP.04-23-2017.21-21-57.Boot_1.etl.zip?dl=0 . (compressed : 101 Mo , uncompressed : 884 Mo )

Comment: Question one - what services have you disabled?
Question two - How many applications do you have set to "Enabled" in the startup tab of your task manager?
Question three - What are your system specifications?
Question four - What version of Windows 10 are you using, and what build number? The .sys file you mentioned is a DirectX component.
Have you tried to reinstall DirectX?

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw from the trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I loaded the ETL into `WPA.exe`, I clicked on `Profile`-> `Apply`, "`browse catalog`" and select the file `FullBoot.Boot.wpaprofile` I saw this overview

[image]

Here the WinLogonInit subphase is slow (79 seconds):

> **What Happens in This Subphase** 
>   The WinLogonInit subphase begins when SMSSInit completes and starts Winlogon.exe. During WinLogonInit,
>   the user logon screen appears, the service control manager starts
>   services, and Group Policy scripts run. WinLogonInit ends when the
>   Explorer process starts.
>
> **Visual Cues** WinLogonInit begins shortly before the logon screen appears. It ends just before the desktop appears for the first time.
>
> **WinLogonInit Performance Vulnerabilities** Many operations occur in parallel during WinLogonInit. On many systems, this subphase is CPU
>   bound and has large I/O demands. Good citizenship from the services
>   that start in this phase is critical for optimized boot times.
>       Services can declare dependencies or use load order groups to ensure that they start in a specific order. Windows processes load
>   order groups in serial order. **Service initialization delays in an
>   early load order group block subsequent load order groups and can
>   possibly block the boot process** .

And here the `CreateSession`is slow:

[image]

and here the `TrustedInstaller` is working (component to install updates). Do you see error messages during shutdown/boot that changes must be reverted? I see that your kernel is 15063.138, but the BuildLab string is still `15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834`. So maybe your Windows is in an inconsistent state. Remove the update KB4015583 via controlpanel->programs & features ->installed updates, reboot and reinstall the update.

Next the `ExplorerInit` phase is also slow and takes 48 seconds to finish:

**What Happens in This Subphase**

> The ExplorerInit subphase begins when Explorer.exe starts. During
>   ExplorerInit, the system creates the desktop window manager (DWM)
>   process, which initializes the desktop and displays it for the first
>   time. This phase is CPU intensive. The initialization of DWM and
>   desktop occurs in the foreground, while in the background the service
>   control manager (SCM) starts services and the memory manager
>   prefetches code and data. On most systems ExplorerInit is CPU bound,
>   and timing issues are likely the result of a simple resource
>   bottleneck.
>   **Visual Cues** 
> ExplorerInit begins just before the desktop appears for the first time. There is no clear visual cue to indicate the end
>   of ExplorerInit.

Here the steps `PreStartTasks`,`LaunchExperienceHost` (Startmenu, action center all the new UI) and `PerUserSetup` are slow:

[image]

When I look at the disk graph, I see that the disk is busy during all boot phases:

[image]

So, your slow 1TB Seagate Samsung Spinpoint M8 (ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB) also slows down boot a lot.

The best is to remove the DVD drive, buy a HDD caddy add the HDD here and use a SSD for the OS + programs.

But attention, make sure you buy a caddy that has a jumper

[image]

to [prevent ACPI.sys issues](https://superuser.com/a/979767/174557).

Comment: Great thanks for your analysis with full details. If you can resume the todo list please (already choose your answer as best possible one)?

Comment: replace HDD with SSD gives you most perf boost. first insert the SSD into the hdd caddy, boot from HDD, use a clone tool to clone Windows to SSD, shutdown, swap drives, so that HDD is on caddy and now boot from SSD.