# Windows 10 very long startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, performance, wpa

I have a MSI GS43VR 6RE laptop. It's pretty powerful and I have 2 SSDs (512 GB M.2 + 1TB Sata) instead of original SSD 128GB + HDD 1TB. Startup time always took about 2-3 seconds. After one of big Windows 10 updates (not sure which one, but it probably was Spring Creators Update) startup time increased to couple of minutes (the part when I see MSI logo on black background and spinning circle loader). I ignored it for a long time because everything else was working fine and I was hoping that it will be fixed in next update(s). But still no changes so I finally decided to make clean windows install and forget about this problem. But surprisingly it didn't help. I tried to install manufacturer drivers from MSI website and I also tried to install latest drivers but it also didn't help. BIOS is latest version, tried to set default settings. I believe this is something that came with updates because I found a lot of reports from different people with same problem. Unfortunately I didn't found solution that works for me so I'm asking here.
[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1202478/windows-10-boot-time-previously-20-seconds-now-6-8-x-more) I found something similar (but not same) and instruction how to create ETL report file for Windows Boot.  So I did (unpacked and Zipped - which is better for you guys). Strange thing is that almost all boot time is Idle, i don't known what does it mean. Or maybe I missed something and there is a way to look deeper? And also I have ntbtlog.txt which also has strange moments, look here:

```
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
...
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys


BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CAD.sys
...
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CAD.sys


BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\NDProxy.sys
...
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\NDProxy.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\NDProxy.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\NDProxy.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\NDProxy.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\NDProxy.sys
```

So it loads this files first time and after that it tries to load them again and again. Here is full versions of my diagnostic  files:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!ArTf1Gx90XNakNQbupjd9T8-MJHANw

Comment: Do you see the same issue without the Fortinet FortiClient software installed?  Maybe you can try renaming FortiShield.sys (C:\windows\system32\drivers\) to FortiShield.sys.off and reboot.  Does that help?  There is also Fortifilter.sys (NDIS filter) and fortifw2.sys, hence if you can remove Fortinet software it might be easier.

Comment: Just tried: removed FortiClient completely, rebooted twice and made sure that forti files removed from system32\drivers folder. Unfortunately problem still exists.

Comment: OK, my only other thought is it's related to Bluetooth somehow. bthport.sys.  Can you disable bluetooth on the device?  The fact a re-install of Windows didn't help might also suggest it's some interaction with the hardware.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help also. Can you at least tell me how did you find that this this drivers causes problems? I just want to understand where to look because the only suspicious thing I see is "Idle" for a 70 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason and it's very stupid. It's because of inserted SD adapter without microSD card in it. Very strange because I always had this adapter inserted in all my laptops (including this) because I need from time to time and it didn't cause any troubles until spring creators update.