# Very long time waiting during Windows boot-Stuck (and doing nothing) during circling dots

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

as the title suggests, the Windows is stuck in the "Windows Logo" with the circling dots screen. During this wait time (about 25minutes) the PC does nothing.
The specs are the following

- **Dell Optiplex 5050**
- Intel Core i7 7700
- 4x16GB (64GB total) DDR4 RAM
- Intel nvme ssd 512GB SSDPEKKF512G8 NVMe INTEL 512GB
- HDD 2TB TOSHIBA DT01ACA200
- Integrated intel graphics, audio
- No other external or internal devices connected
- Windows 10 22H2

I've tried the following
Removed HDD, removed GPU and AUDIO devices from device manager and reinstall it, windows updated, tracing with boot trace, removed AVAST antivirus, updated all the drivers to the latest one. Deactivated both secureboot and fastboot. These steps have been performed one at a time to eliminate possible culprits. Nothing worked, the exact same behaviour. It seems that for some reason, there is a "waittime" or "timeout"/"sleep" time after windows starts to boot. But I can't find anything in msconfig in order to adjust it. Also the BIOS doesn't have such an option.

Any ideas kindly appreciated!

[SSD SMART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkDQa.png)[HDD SMART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ39e.png)

Additional info: Using chkdsk, no errors have been found. Also checks to the windows integrity (using DSM tool), return no errors. The following "Not loaded" info is provided in bootlog (multiple times each)

- BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
- BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\aswMonFlt.sys
- BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\NDProxy.sys

Comment: Have you ensured that the SSD is still working correctly? A failing bootdrive can slow down the startup process. You can run CrystalDiskInfo and read the SMART status

Comment: Please copy the SMART attributes section to your post. You could also run `chkdsk` and test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Enable boot logging using `msconfig`, reboot then check the log.

Comment: Also, examine the Event Viewer for interesting messages.

Comment: I have run chkdsk on both drives...no errors found. I have also tested Windows integrity...no errors found... I will update the initial post with the requested info.

Comment: Did your problems start after installing Avast? Also https://superuser.com/questions/1409345/windows-10-very-long-startup

Comment: No, I've completely uninstalled avast and the same behavior exists.

Comment: If you reinstalled Windows; and if your drive is OK; then consider a motherboard error.

Comment: Although the drive does not log errors, it does show a lot of wear. The drive might still be failing. You could consider benchmarking it.

Comment: This is not the SMART data we need - we need  something like [that](https://imgur.com/D1dhnF8). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc https://imgur.com/JdpPQUR and https://imgur.com/paB7DU9

Comment: @LPChip How to benchmark? CrystalDiskMark shows the following https://imgur.com/xFoY4N0

Comment: Your disks are in good shape, the problem is elsewhere. Try a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: See Harrymc's reply.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing worked. Hereunder is the bootlog (if helps) https://filebin.net/qhfvz4gwzz8a7vu4

I uninstalled avast and bought bitdefender in its place. However, even during Safe mode startup, the problem persists. It seems that windows try to load a driver but fails, and then waits after each retry