# Can I install a SSD drive in my DVD drive slot

Tags: installation, ssd

Can I insert a new SSD drive into my laptop DVD slot and use it as a second boot drive. I will be using Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Probably depends on the make / model of the laptop (you should add the make / model to the question).  It is pretty easy to see if there is a Hard Drive Bay Adapter once you know the model.

Comment: Probably not, unless you can find/use the appropriate disk caddy.  The DVD/optical drive typically has a different style of SATA power connector than the HDD/SSD style.  https://www.google.com/search?q=laptop+disk+caddy&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 3):

To by able to use a 2nd HDD/SSD in the slot where the DVD drive was, you need to buy a HDD caddy. But make sure the Caddy you buy has a jumper on it,

[image]

[otherwise you may run into ACPI.sys DPC/Interrupt issues](https://superuser.com/a/1152438/174557) ([2nd example](https://superuser.com/a/979767/174557)) which slows down the device and causes battery drain.

For stability (I saw unstable Windows when running a SSD in a caddy) and performance reasons, put the SSD in the native HDD slot and use the old HDD in the hdd caddy.

With this configuration I run a SSD/HDD combination for over 4 years.