# Process Explorer (sysinternals), save lines/graphs as txt?

Tags: windows, memory, dump, profiling

I'm using the "Process Explorer" from sysinternals to monitor the memory consumption of a specific process over time. This is quite helpful for the first step.

For I a deeper analysis I would like to save the curves of the "performance graph" (called private bytes) to a txt-file. Is there any how I can handle that task?

[image: Screenshot of Performance Graph]

Or is another program with which I can get this functionality?

Thank you

Comment: there is no way to save them. to analyze the CPU usage use WPR/WPA: http://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557 check which process causes the CPU usage and extract the stack of the process to see more details

Comment: I believe [perfmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749154(v=ws.11).aspx) will allow you to save the logs to be reviewed.

Comment: @heavyd yeah, but for a detailed troubleshooting WPR/WPA is better , for long term overview checking, perfmon is better because it creates smaller files.