# Why does Task Manager have high CPU utilization?

Tags: windows-10

I've been noticing that Task Manager itself has been experiencing high CPU utilization, often in the 15 to 40% range with the update speed set to normal.

The problem is intermittent and after a few minutes (I'd guess 5 to 10 min) it does eventually calm down. Restarting the Task Manager doesn't solve this.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: And your CPU is?

Comment: According to task manager: i7-5500U 2.40GHz

Comment: analyze CPU usage with WPR/WPA: https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557 expand the callstack of `taskmgr.exe` and from the function names you should see that `taskmgr.exe` does.