# I get higher than normal CPU usage from "System" whenever transferring or downloading files

Tags: windows-8.1, file-transfer, cpu-usage, download-manager

Whenever I am downloading something, or I am copying files from one place to another, I get higher than normal CPU usage (10% - 25%) from the "System" process (NT Kernel & System). If I pause the downloads (currently using Internet Download Manager with 13 files downloading), the CPU usage drops to below 1%. Internet Download Manager also is using significant CPU, up to 20%. 
I also see this sometimes, but not as badly, when I am copying files from my mechanical storage drive to my NAS.

I wouldn't think file downloads/transfers would be a very CPU intensive process, but I really don't get why I am seeing it from the System Kernel process. Does anyone have any ideas as to what the hell is going on here? I have never seen this particular one before and am at a bit of a loss.

This is on 64 bit Windows 8.1 with an AMD FX-8350 oct-core CPU, a 500GB Samsung EVO solid state drive, 32GB of RAM, and Kaspersky Total Security as well as HitmanPro.Alert anti-ransomware.

Comment: what protocol are you asking about? I believe that the SMB client runs from the system process (pid 4). use netstat to identify the port the transfer is occuring over, and note the PID involved. and yes, many downloads are in fact CPU intensive, due to technologies like transport compression, checksum validation, etc. depends entirely on the protocol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubleshoot High CPU usage by the "System" process](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process)

Comment: use the SDK/WPT to diag the CPU usage as I explained in [my answer in the duplicate](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557)