# RtlSidHashInitialize thread high CPU utilization on WIndows

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage

On my Windows 10 system, the System process is continuously clocking ~12% CPU utilization (1 logical processor).

Process explorer shows that

> ntoskrnl.exe!RtlSidHashInitialize+0x1450

thread is consuming all of it.

I read that it could be a driver issue, but I have no clue about how to nail it down to particular driver.
Any clues on how to diagnose this further?

Comment: If you (still in Process Explorer) double click on that line, it shows the stack. Can you see any driver files listed there?

Comment: the cause is somewhere lese, you missed to configure symbols. [use WPRUI/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557) to analyze the cpu usage. I posted a lot of examples of issues I saw over the years.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thread "ntoskrnl.exe!RtlSidHashInitialize+0x1450" constantly consuming 30-60% CPU on a Server 2016 Build 1607 VM. I see several other posts about this thread, but no details about what is causing the behavior. Time to dig deeper.

Comment: In my case, it turned out to be norton internet security, in case this helps anyone.