# Microsoft Software Protection Platform Service high cpu usage

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage

In Windows 10, Microsoft Software Protection Platform Service is using more than 30% of my cpu.  I tried the things listed here:

https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-high-cpu-usage-by-sppsvc-exe-on-windows-10/

The first 2 don't work and when I disable it with the 3rd method the cpu usage problem goes away, but a message is displayed in the corner of my screen in gray text saying "Activate Windows Go to Settings to activate Windows" that displays on top of everything else and never goes away. Is there anything I can do other than reinstalling Windows?

Comment: @Biswa How do I do that? I just followed the instructions in the link I posted and I don't really know what it means. Here's a picture of the things I'm able to change if that helps

http://i.imgur.com/6V15bxo.png

Comment: Change the hex value to **2**. Then type the command as admin:: `net start sppsvc`

Comment: [use WPR/WPA.exe to analyze the CPU usage](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557) (expand the stack of sppsvc.exe instead of system and look at the function names to see what the service does)

Comment: it takes more than 40% of my CPU usages.link: https://superuser.com/q/1330789/914103

Answer (score 1):

If you tried the regedit solution, make sure to get the Start value in
 Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\sppsvc set to its previous value (2 instead of 4) so Windows and other Microsoft products can get back to normal.

---

The only alternative solution i found is :

1. download
   [processHacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io),install and run
   it
2. look for sppsvc.exe (you can use the search bar)
3. right click on the process and click suspend.
4. **Optional**:quit process hacker.

---

You should suspend it every startup,unless you found out a way to automate this.
UPDATE : suspending sppsvc.exe will cause Office to crash often.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem really easy in my way!

1. Find you `sppsvc` file on you Local Disk (C:),
   then right click on it and click Properties.
2. In Properties you will find on top side next to General and Digital Signatures tab named Compatibility, click on it.
3. In Compatibility tab find Compatibility mode.
   if the options in that window are grey, change settings for all users that can be found on the bottom side of you Properties window
   and after that check the box ''Run this program in compatibility mode for:''
   And change compatibility mode to      Windows Vista          problem solved

**Note:**
This settings will remove your Microsoft software protection platform service, but
it may make Activate Windows watermark. If you want to remove that follow these easy
2 minute steps on this site: https://www.hows.tech/2017/04/how-to-buy-windows-10-and-activate-from.html

Answer (score 1):

> This is a temporary solution but very effective. **Remember you have do it once on every time you reboot your PC.**

1. Go to Task Manager -> Performance tab -> Open resource monitior.[image]

2.Go to CPU tab and select sppsvc.exe and right click over it.[image]

3.Select Suspend Process.

As i do not restart my laptop or hardly restart so this process helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Any method to disable sppsvc will also deactivate all your microsoft products including windows.  If you suspend the service, (you can do that with resource monitor.  No need for a third party software) the high cpu problem will be resolved but MS Office will hang after a few minutes as it tries to do a validation request to the suspended service.

Contrary to the windows activation process, until MSO receives a positive response from the service, it will wait for an answer, while windows will just postpone the validation for a later time.

So here's the current situation, as of december 31st 2018 : Suspending the service is a good workaround if you need the CPU power for a game.  Once you are done, you can re-enable it and use MS Office or anything else that doesnt need intense CPU process.

This is the only workaround that i know of, as i searched for a solution for the last 9 months daily.