# Stopping Microsoft Software Protection Platform Service service

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, cpu-usage

The Microsoft Software Protection Platform Service process is using more than 40% of CPU usage.

How do I stop this nonsense.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can disable that service in Windows Services until you find a solution....also see this page....https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-high-cpu-usage-by-sppsvc-exe-on-windows-10/

Comment: Have you restarted the PC? Updated to the latest build of W10?

Comment: this server handles Windows activation. check if you have activation issues

Comment: service cant be disabled,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Software Protection Platform Service high cpu usage](https://superuser.com/questions/1244731/microsoft-software-protection-platform-service-high-cpu-usage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already answered this question.
Refer to my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1244731/microsoft-software-protection-platform-service-high-cpu-usage/1318015#1318015).

**Note** : using this solution will cause crashes in MS Office products, and its the only solution i've found so far. If you are fine with products like WPS Office,Ashampoo Office,OpenOffice or LibreOffice,then this should be the right solution for you.

Comment: I've been waiting for an update to solve this issue,but it seems that this isnt an 'issue',everytime i foce a MS program to close,this 'Microsoft software protection plateform' popup on the task manager. as i am only comfortable with using MS Office,i had to let it do what it does and stopped worrying about it.