# Thundebrid eats nearly all of my system resources. Anything I can do about it?

Tags: windows-7, performance, thunderbird

My Thunderbird (newest version) eats nearly all my system resources (45-85% of CPU).

Computer's cooler runs loudly and using any application (including Thunderbird itself) is simply impossible because mail messages are being typedletter-by-letter with 2-3 seconds delay between each letter.

I have quite old but still usable hardware -- Asus notebook with i5 quad and 8 GB of RAM.

**What can I do (what to check, what tests to perform) to try to find source of this problem?**

I can't believe that this is hardware-related problem, because 50+ other applications works like a charm on the very same computer. I can't (now) believe this is Thunderbird-related problem, since it seems it is working awfully slow on my computer only.

Yes, I did all the magic with creating new profile and/or reinstalling Thunderbird itself.

Comment: So if you don't have 50 applications running in the background. Does Thunderbird still have this performance problem?

Comment: I have removed most of the waffle and opinionated rants - hopefully the question is easier to read now

Comment: [capture the cpu usgae with WPRUI and analyze it with WPA.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557). at the step to configure debug symbols, also add the Mozilla symbol sever: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Using_the_Mozilla_symbol_server

Comment: @Ramhound Either I don't understand your question or you don't understands mine. I'm talking about situation when I have Google Chrome with one tab run as _the only_ applications and system resources "hunger" (except for Thunderbird) is at 2-3% level. Then I start up Thunderbird as second application of all, system resources consumption goes up to 45-85% and using Thunderbird or Gmail is virtually impossible.

Comment: "because 50+ other applications works like a charm on the very same computer." - I took this as you were running 50+ applications.

Comment: again, analyze the cpu usage with WPRUI/WPA