# System slowed down, SSD suspected

Tags: ssd, performance, cpu-usage

My mobile workstation (i7, 16GB RAM) became really slow (even the mouse moves are shown with 1FPS), CPU usage at 100% even when nothing at all was running. After a few minutes even worse.
I have rebooted and tried to run an offline BitDeffender scan, which could not manage to parse a 100MB file in 10s.
Then I booted up using a mobile HDD, over just a USB2 cable. And it is even so faster like a rocket and with normal CPU usage.
Now I am suspecting my mSATA SSD (Samsung EVO 840)
Then I have downloaded Samsung SSD Magician and HDDTune and ran some tests:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

The benchmarks look really meaningful:

[image: screenshot 4]

[image: screenshot 5]

[image: screenshot 6]

**Really low minimum and really high CPU usage, but even the maximum transfer rate is far below specs.**

The SMART health status is OK:

[image]

And here is the speed map:

[image]

Is this the end of the SSD or the end of something on the motherboard - quite not uninteresting from cost point of view?

Comment: the 840 Evo had perf issues when files were not accessed for a longer time. There was a firmware update which refreshed the drive more often. flash the last firmware.

Comment: have you tried the new firmware?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the firmware. The profile looks better, but still far below specs, still high cpu load. And the overheating is still there.

Comment: the 840 Evo has TLC NAND issues so the perf will never be the same as in the specs. which process has the CPU usage? if SYSTEM process, [look at this guide to trace it](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557)