# Connected Bluetooth device and high kernel time

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, high-cpu-usage

I have connected a DualShock 4 controller to my Windows 10 machine and after around 30 minutes of usage (or simply leaving it connected) the kernel time on my first CPU core is at ~100% usage.

If I disconnect it after that the core usage drops to normal but after reconnecting it the usage goes up again.

What can I do to prevent it from happening?

I'm using a Gigabyte WB867D-I (Intel Dual-Band Wireless-AC 8265) for Bluetooth connection.

ETL for analyzing: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14VecTYp5fySKZjmrWYY9in33h50ZAupX

New ETL for Analyzing: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S7vMaCUfe1TYpLpiJ-o5kukW5TRRFgCi

Comment: [analyze the CPU usage](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557). look if it is he Bluetooth driver

Comment: did that and found nothing and it's not the System process.

Comment: share (onedrive share link) the generated ETL (zip the ETL first to reduce file size), maybe I see more.

Comment: added the ETL to my post.

Comment: I can only see <5% cpu usage of all kernel/SYSTEM calls across all processes. run the command, play it and when you see the high usage, disconnect the controller and now stop tracing.

Comment: that was exactly what i did on that etl but i will try again

Comment: Okay. I added a new ETL to the post. I hope you can "see" something now.

Comment: no diference. I see CPU usage of "X:\Game Files\Need for Speed Underground 2\SPEED2.EXE" which is your game and atfer this point, the cpu usage drops . how do you determine issues? With taslmgr? In Wi10 taskmanager shows 100% usage were no use occurs due to a bug. [play with power plan settings to fix it](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.borncity.com%2Fblog%2F2015%2F07%2F31%2Fwindows-10-bug-zeigt-100-cpu-auslastung-im-taskmanager%2F%23comment-32706&edit-text=)

Comment: I have the taskmgr running on my second screen and the pc starts stuttering alot when this happens. [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H8zVHibmyMiAyiuVKvCy-Y9riY38Fyag)

Comment: taskmgr has a bug in high performance mode (which you may use to disable core parking for your AMD Ryzen CPU to get best performance). Run ProcessExplorer instaed to look if you have CPU usage or not.

Comment: ProccessExplorer shows the same high kernel time.

Comment: But I can't see it in the trace.

Comment: Ist there another way to analyze, maybe specifically the Interrupts? Because I saw that under the SYSTEM proccess Interrupts goes from <1% up to "only" ~5% utilization.

Comment: interrupts /DPC are also low (ISR: 0.05%, DPC: 0.01%)

Comment: I just found out that I just have the problem only with my DualShock 4 controller. I tested it with another Bluetooth controller and I could play for hours without the kernel time problem.

Comment: ok, post this as answer and only use this other controller.