# Win10: Is there a way to view the exact process involved in "Service Host: Remote Procedure Call?"

Tags: windows, windows-10

Lately task manager has been sporadically showing a process called "Service host: remote procedure call" having suddenly spiked to about 20% processor power.  Even though it's only at 20%, my computer jams to a halt, and I have to wait 20-30s for it to resolve. Video and audio continue to run in the background, but I cannot make any inputs such as switching windows or interacting with any software.

If I am in the middle of something remotely intensive (like watching a video), and happen to click e.g. pause/play/fullscreen before I realize this process is currently spiking, it can exacerbate the freeze for several minutes before the service host returns to normal and my computer is usable again. If I'm too persistent about switching windows or opening task manager, sometimes windows explorer will crash and have to reboot first.

Throughout this entire time, my processor's total usage never exceeds ~30% or ~40-50% memory. Everything there looks normal.

As I understand it, service host: remote procedure call is a blanket label for many different processes, like svchost is (or maybe they are the same thing—open file location does in fact direct me to svchost.exe).

Can I do anything, perhaps in cmd menu, to force windows to display what this exact task is next time it's spiking, so I can identify the problem and take measures to troubleshoot it?

Thanks

Comment: [analyze cpu usage](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557) with Windows Performance Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

From a command prompt run this:
tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eq svchost.exe"

See this site for more detailed info:
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/list-services-running-under-svchostexe-process/

Comment: Q: Is there a way to view ***the exact process*** involved in “Service Host: Remote Procedure Call?”  This answer lists *all* the `svchost` processes, not just the one the question is talking about.