# Random CPU peaks?

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

Recently I have been experiencing random peaks in my computers CPU, while keeping task manager open I see various applications take their turn in hogging my CPU. I open a simple application like notepad and it'll be quick to take 40% of my CPU.

It'll let that die down then another application will hog another lets say 37%, next thing I know another application has grabbed 70% of my CPU and my CPU is at 99%.

It isn't as mad with the memory as I use high-intensive applications such as resharper and other things, but basioc applications using 50% cpu really isn't right.

What is wrong with my computer? Firefox is currently peaking at 20%, it'll begin to die down from 20 to 17, to 13, to 7 and then another application will grab my CPU and hog it, its a constant cycle.

I'm running windows 10 with 8GB ram, with Intel Core i3 2120 @ 3.30GHz. My temprature of my CPU is currently peaking at around 56 °C if this means anything?

Full view of my specs:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/VyhISEM.png]

Comment: Why are some people voting to close this post as unclear? Seems quite clear to me.

Comment: [analyze the cpu usage of the processes](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557) as I showed several times. expand the stack of the processes with high Weight (%) and look for the function names on the tack. they should tell you want the tool does.

Answer (score 2):

Normal, totally normal.

My CPU has the same temperature as you, it usually shows 57 °C, other hardware also show the similar temperature than yours, by the way, my machine is a new one, I bought it a week ago.

About CPU usage and peak, I don’t see any trouble:

Open more apps leads to a higher usage, die down programs leads to a gradually drop, no problem.

Microsoft has a monitor tool called Process Explorer can view process’s behaviors and CPU state, you can have a try.

Also, there are many CPU check tool online, use it for test.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad will not take 40% of your CPU, unless some software has injected
itself into its process-space.

I believe that your computer must be infected with a virus which might
be doing coin-mining while trying (clumsily) to disguise its activity.

For more information see our post :
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Downvoter: Bravo for downvoting a probably correct answer.