# The `System` process has a high CPU usage. ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLock+0x1e0 is the culprit. How to fix it?

Tags: windows-7, kernel, cpu-usage

I noticed that the `System` process has a high CPU usage (specifically, around 100% of 1 core). Following [Troubleshoot High CPU usage by the "System" process](https://superuser.com/a/527557/116475), I opened the properties of `System` in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and see that the `ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLock+0x1e0` is the one using most of the CPU. What could the issue should be?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is no need to do a new post, you already found the correct topic, but used the wrong answer to solve your issue. Next time use WIndows Performance toolkit. The 10586 SDK/WPT also works for Win7.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, I agree I should have followed your answer. I'll add a screenshot in your answer next time I have the issue (e.g., when I'll need the Wi-Fi again, which may happen soon).

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried to use WPA to understand the cause of the highly CPU usage from system.exe: I didn't see anything suspicious under `ntoskrnl.exe!`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whqCQ.png Do you have any insight on further analysis that I could do?

Comment: you need to [load the debug symbols first](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/loading-symbols)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the Wi-Fi adapters, then rebooted the computer: it seems to have done the trick.

Specifically, in the `Device Manager`, I disable the 3 adapters:

[image]

To disable them, I right-clicked on each of them, and chose  `Disable`:

[image]

I found out that the issue came from the Wi-Fi by killing processes one by one: killing them didn't affect how much CPU `ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLock+0x1e0` was using, except when I killed some processes related to the Wi-Fi (which caused `ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLock+0x1e0`'s CPU use shortly decrease, and then went back to "normal", i.e. eating ~100% of one core)

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained how you worked out it was the Wireless adapters causing the issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill Good point, added