# CPU under load despite removing all process affinities

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, affinity

I've installed *Process Lasso* and in *All processes* tab, set all affinities to 1-7, meaning that all the processes can be start on all my CPUs except the first one. Yet, there is a huge load on my first CPU.

I personally have no clue what's happening here and really appreciate any help.

My system is:

- Intel core i7 - 4720 HQ  2.6 GHz upto 3.6
- Windows 10 (64 bit)
- NVidia GTX 950 M

This screenshot, shows the software's interface. Those 8 green bars on upper right show my CPU usage. Also the column called *Rules*, indicates the affinities on the processes.

[image: Screenshot of my desktop]

---

PS: These are screenshots that show the more familiar Task Manager and Resource Monitor. I've sorted all with respect to their CPU usage. Note that the overall CPU usage is just fine (less than 30% most of the time), but in Resource Monitor, same as the *Process Lasso*, it's obvious that that most of the load is on CPU0 and the others are almost free.

Also I found out that my total CPU usage, is actually more than all my processes altogether! The orange line in Resource Monitor picture, shows the amount of CPU usage of all my processes. (I did the same in safe mode. Orange line, exactly coincides the total usage in safe mode. So I'm suspecting that something is happening in my normal boot.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The CPU is taken by `dwm.exe` which is the Desktop Window Manager, responsible for drawing the desktop and all its effects. Do you have some process that is continually updating the desktop display?

Comment: Desktop windows manager is not that huge in terms of cpu load I suppose. Anyhow, I'm not sure if any app is updating desktop continuously. At least I see nothing in Task manager or Resource monitor. Is it possible that somrthing is not shown there? although I'm the admin and the only user on this machine.

Comment: Could you please use the Windows Task Manager rather than Process Lasso? (I trust it more.)

Comment: @harrymc I edited my question. Now it has the image of both Task Manager and Resource Monitor.

Comment: system process /kernel) uses the CPU. so [analyze the issue as I wrote in my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557). Next time, use search

Answer (score 0):

The heaviest CPU user is now "System" which is Windows itself and the hardest to
diagnose.
I suggest to :

- Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) to check your setup
- If that finds nothing, check if Windows and all your drivers are fully updated.
- See if this happens when no processes are running.

  - If it does, then have try booting in Safe mode, and if the problem
    disappears then some installed product is the cause.
  - If it does not happen, then try to terminate processes when it happens
    until you find the troublemaker.
- Try to disconnect all unnecessary devices to see if this is caused by one
  of them.
- Run deep antivirus scans by several known such products, including
  [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).
- You will find some more hints in
  [this article](https://fossbytes.com/how-to-fix-high-ram-and-cpu-usage-of-windows-10-system-ntoskrnl-exe-process/).
- Otherwise, you will need to analyze the cause, as described in
  [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2008/04/07/the-case-of-the-system-process-cpu-spikes/),
  although that requires some Windows knowledge.

If nothing works, you will have to decide if the problem is serious enough
to take some risks and spend hours on it.

Comment: 1. I've run memory scan twice. This is what happens: it seems that it performs 6 tests on the memory that takes quite a while (around 1.5 hour in my laptop). After finishing all tests, it simply starts another epoch. In both cases it found nothing wrong with the memory. But I forced shutdown or exited the scan to avoid another 2 hours of waiting.

2. The problem exists in safe mode as well. But I haven't checked the processes there yet.

3. No device is connected.

Comment: The problem existing in Safe mode means Windows is corrupted. Please concentrate on SFC and antivirus scans, before taking steps to repair Windows.

Comment: ""System" which is Windows itself and the hardest to diagnose" this is very easy [with Windows Performance Toolkit](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557)

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thank you, this will be useful.