# No "Stack" column in Windows Performance Analyzer

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to follow the instructions answered in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process?newreg=430a2d3f5da8494e96634bb5d3312e2b) that use the WPA to identify what's happening in the System process. The answer in that question contains this screenshot:

[image]

But when I open the WPA and follow the instructions, I can't see the stack column:

[image]

[image]

How can I see the Stack column?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the column headings?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes it just shows the same options as in the second screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You need to open "CPU Usage (Sampled)" view, not "CPU Usage (Attributed)"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).