# What does Windows 10 "System" task keep doing in the background all the time?

Tags: windows-10, bloatware

I keep hearing my PC's fans slightly speeding up and seeing "System" running in the processes list at under 20% CPU load:

[image: Windows 10: System process constantly running in background]

I assume the task is throttled in order to be as inconvenient as possible.

But what the hugg is it doing, why does it need to run this every day?

I never noticed similar stuff in MacOS or Linux. I also tried to disable telemetry 'features', but that doesn't seem to be it. It certainly feels like some bloatware Microsoft would put in an OS, but I can't figure out what exactly and how to disable it if I don't need it.

Comment: High CPU usage by the "System" process can often be caused by a hardware driver issue (bug, old version, incompatility etc). Kindly check if the answers in this similar thread can help you: [Troubleshoot High CPU usage by the “System” process](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process)

Comment: The "System" process is the heart of Windows (the Kernel). It is not bloatware. Follow Sunny's recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

In a properly operating machine, "system" will not use very much CPU (< 3% over time).

If it is an issue, look at this Microsoft Article

[Fixes for System High CPU](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/the-system-process-in-task-manager-using-unusually/97e99b84-4890-400b-b5ac-0abab44ad464)

Key points:

> 3. Update your drivers and BIOS/UEFI firmware from PC or motherboard
>    maker's Support Downloads web page, using the full model number,
>    Serial Number or Dell Service Tag on sticker. Compare the latest
>    drivers available for download with the ones presently installed in
>    Device Manager reached by right clicking the Start button. Make sure
>    you have the latest BIOS or UEFI firmware, Chipset, Display (Video),
>    Sound, USB3, Bluetooth, Network and all other drivers, or else
>    download and install the latest now.
>
> Updating drivers from the Device Manager or Windows Update is rarely
> enough. The most basic thing we need to learn to maintain a PC is keep
> the latest manufacturer's drivers installed from their Support
> Downloads web page.
>
> 4. If nothing else works then do a Repair Install, by installing Media
>    Creation Tool,

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> open tool and choose to Upgrade Now. This reinstalls
> Windows while keeping files, programs and most settings in place, is
> the most stable method to advance to the latest version, and solves
> most problems

Another tool for locating processes that use CPU is SysInternals Process Explorer.  I use this and it is very helpful

Comment: Hmm thanks. I keep the machine up to date on all fronts, and I don't think it's a misconfiguration or such. It looks like these are some routines that run on a daily basis, and it's annoying because I don't know what it's really doing and if I really need that 'feature' whatever it is.

Comment: My machines here run al low CPU all the time, so go through all the article and then consider the repair install approach.  Also update any Manufacturer's software (update app, diagnostic app, battery threshold app) as well.

Comment: Both OS and hardware related software is up to date. CPU load is not particularly high because System task is throttled to run at around 15% (as far as I noticed). However that doesn't help explain why it is running in the first place and if I can disable said 'feature'.

Comment: System cannot be disabled.  Try SysInternals Process Explorer to see if that helps locate the issue.