# Computer lags with GPU0 at 100% and GPU1 at 0%

Tags: gpu

I have a laptop that often lags/stutters when doing "normal" tasks that are not intensive:

- Firefox with Youtube
- Microsoft Teams make my computer lag with the Desktop App and even when using the App interface with Google Chrome)

Here is my GPU usage[image: my GPU usage]

We can see that 3 apps take roughly 80% of one GPU ("System", Firefox, and "Windows Driver Foundation - Host process..." each take between 20% and 30% of my GPU 0)

Another weird thing is that my second GPU is not used, it stays at 0% even when launching games.

Here are my specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i5-8265U @1.6GHz (4 cores / 8 virtual processors?)
- RAM: 24 GB
- GPU 0: Intel UHD Graphics 620
- GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce MX250

What can I do to further troubleshoot my issue? How can I use both my GPU?

Comment: I believe Windows uses Integrated Graphics (GPU0) for hardware acceleration, but 20-30% usage is a bit higher. I have the exact same specs (except for RAM) and my GPU usage is only about 2-3%. It does spike when switching between windows and performing other similar tasks.

Comment: `Another weird thing is that my second GPU is not used, it stays at 0% even when launching games.` Have you installed driver from NVIDIA? (Not sure if you need to do anything else to enable Optimus...)

Comment: Yup, just installed the driver, switched the settings in the NVidia control panel to always use my MX250 GPU, but did not change anything, games like Skyrim still lag

Comment: "System" shouldn't use that much GPU. I suggest running several deep antivirus scans by well-known antivirus products. Follow also the advice in the post [Troubleshoot High CPU usage by the “System” process](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process). Let us know what you find.

Comment: @TomYan I think installing/updating the NVIDIA driver solved my issue, you can post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the second GPU wasn't configured correctly, so it is detected, but doesn't get used by your applications. I found a solution that you could try: [use Nvidia GPU instead of integrated intel card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72567/can-i-force-steam-to-use-my-nvidia-gpu-instead-of-the-integrated-intel-card)

If Firefox uses too many resources, check your extensions or reinstall Firefox.

To the resourceful “System” process: do a right click on it and check the location of the binary. Bitcoin miner often use the GPU, so it might be one of these. Also, you can use [Microsoft's Malicious Software Remover Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9905) to check your PC.

At the end, if nothing works, check your drivers. I'm recommending [IOBit Driver Booster](https://www.iobit.com/de/driver-booster.php) for this. If all your drivers work, backup your data and reset your PC. This helps in most Software related problems.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I think it was a driver issue.