# High CPU Usage (Spikes) caused by "nvlddmkm.sys"

Tags: drivers, cpu, nvidia

The problem: It's been 2-3 days that my laptop is constantly using the nvidia GPU instead of the integrated one for simple things. Can't find WHAT is using the GPU. Battery autonomy dropped from 3-4 hours to less than 1 hour because of this. System is showing "high power usage", and ~20% CPU usage for no reason.

[image: Task Manager screenshot]

With the help of this post: [Troubleshoot High CPU usage by the "System" process](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process)
I managed to diagnose the issue. Here are the results:

[image: CPU usage analysis]

The spikes are associated with this process : **nvlddmkm.sys**

This is the only process that "stand out" in the analysis, the others have fairly normal values.

What can i do to fix this ? I tried installing the latest nvidia drivers, did windows updates, etc...

My specs:

Serial Number:                9S717F412022ZK5000116
Product Name:                 GF75 Thin 10SCXR
OS:                           Microsoft Windows 10 Famille 64 bits Ver.2009(OS build 19042.1348)
BIOS Version:                 E17F4IMS.108

- Serial Number:                9S717F412022ZK5000116
- Product Name:                 GF75 Thin 10SCXR
- OS:                           Microsoft Windows 10 Famille 64 bits Ver.2009(OS build 19042.1348)
- BIOS Version:                 E17F4IMS.108
- EC Version:                   17F4EMS1.1010914202019:20:18
- CPU:                          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz
- Graphics:                     Intel(R) UHD Graphics, 1024 MB
- Graphics:                     NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, 4096 MB

Comment: Have you expanded the stacks using 4 and 2% with Symbols loaded.  It will be interesting to see what API calls the Nvidia driver is calling.

Comment: That's smart, i edited my question with a better image, thanks !

Comment: You need to configure symbols and the expand all the way down the stack until it comes out of the Nvidia driver in to presumably Microsoft APIs and with symbols we can gain more context.