# Windows 10 High System CPU Usage: hal.dll!<Symbols disabled><itself>

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, cpu-usage, dll

I have a Windows 10 laptop and every time I restart it or power it on from being turned off, the "System" process is always at about 20% CPU usage (the CPU is 4 cores, 8 threads). I followed the instructions here [Troubleshoot High CPU usage by the "System" process](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process) and installed the Windows Performance Analyzer to get a better idea of what could be causing it, but I'm still at a loss.

[image]

I can't find much on `hal.dll!<Symbols disabled><itself>` online, so I'm not sure what this is.

I think this issue may have started after the last Windows update, but I'm not sure.

Any idea on what this is and what else I can do to get the CPU usage back down?

Comment: Since you did a recent Windows Update, update all your drivers and see if that helps.

Comment: @John, does anything in my screenshot indicate which drivers I should try updating? It will take me a while to go through them all one by one and it would help if we could narrow it down to a certain component.

Comment: I would just update all drivers. My manufacturer’s Update App does this.