# High CPU usage realted to "nvlddmkm.sys"

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, windows-11, nvidia-graphics-card

On a notebook one CPU core is constantly at 100 % which causes noise, reduced performance and high power consumption.

The notebook has both an integrated GPU (Intel UHD Graphics) and a dedicated one (NVIDIA Quadro T1000). It runs on Windows 11 22H2. The driver installed is "NVIDIA Graphics Driver 546.09". The notebook is a DELL Precision 5550.

Trying to figure out what causes it I did the following (mostly like described here: https://superuser.com/a/1164299/707770):

- Collect performance data using `Xperf -on latency -stackwalk profile -buffersize 1024 -MaxFile 256 - FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d cpuusage.etl`
- Load the file in the "Windows Performance Analyzer"
- Use menu "Trace" > "Load symbols" (which then took quite a while to load those)
- Added `srv*c:\symbols*https://driver-symbols.nvidia.com/` as symbol path (see https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-driver-symbol-server)

Still I do not see what exactly causes the troubles:

[image: Print screen of Windows Performance Analyzer]

- Where do I get the missing symbols from?
- What causes the CPU load exactly?
- How do I dig deeper on this?

Update 1: **I uninstalled the driver** using "Add or remove programs". After a reboot **Windows Update installed a driver again**. This new driver is not visible as an installed app any more. With the new driver, **the issues with the CPU load are gone**.

Update 2: The issue is back . Any help is very much appreciated.

Update 3: The driver version affected is **31.0.15.4609**. The only thing that helped was to **roll back the driver version** using the Windows **Device Manager** to an earlier version.

Comment: Nvidia hasn’t published the driver symbols for  "nvlddmkm.sys" which likely means they don’t exist, specifically, you have likely diagnostic the issue to the correct driver.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minor update to the Update 3 method Adrian posted, but was easier than rolling back the old driver.

After experiencing the same problem with the **system.exe** collection of processes consuming one core, I followed the same instructions https://superuser.com/a/1164299/707770 and also found that the **nvlddmkm.sys** process was the culprit. (No need to do the symbol search per Ramhound)

Instead of downgrading the driver from 31.0.15.4609 as Adrian posted, I instead went to the NVIDIA Driver site https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us and downloaded a more current driver (31.0.15.5123 in my case, which was part of the 551.23  WHQL install package).  After downloading the WHQL package, that driver will install automatically, and it corrected my problem.

Comment: For me, downgrading didn't help, but upgrading to the latest driver directly from NVIDIA did solve the issue.